# Actualizar con un valor el registro en LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql-server

Buen día ... tengo esta consulta

```html
select  Numeros.n ,coalesce(Numeros.IdPaciente, datos.IdPaciente) IdPaciente,  FechaAnalitica,GlucosaPre,Sodio,Calcio from Numeros 
left join
(
    select ROW_NUMBER () over (order by IdPaciente asc) Row#,
    IdPaciente,FechaAnalitica,GlucosaPre,Sodio,Calcio
    from ANA_BIOQUIMICA where IdPaciente = 2450
)datos
on Numeros.n = datos.Row#
```

este me devuelve el siguiente resultado :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero necesito, que la columna "Id Paciente" no devuelva null, sino que devuelva el mismo valor que los registros de arriba...

¿Como puedo lograr esto?

Gracias por compartir su experiencia ..

Comment: Para esto tienes varias opciones:
1. Agregar un Where IdPaciente is not null
2. En lugar de usar left join utiliza inner join
3. En caso de que sea estrictamente necesario traer la fila 11, utiliza la función **LAG** para ir al valor del IdPaciente del registro anterior

Comment: Lo que entiendo que ocurre es que la consulta sobre `ANA_BIOQUIMICA where IdPaciente = 2450` te retorna 10 filas y la tabla `Numeros` tiene al menos 11 filas. El `idPaciente` lo estas configurado de manera "dura" por que no entonces `coalesce(Numeros.IdPaciente, datos.IdPaciente, 2450)`?

Comment: Gracias... no puedo usar el hard code, el where lo use solo para delimitar el conjunto de datos, pero no debe aparecer en la consulta real.. por otro lado ... necesito el registro producto de la relación left join

Comment: ponle un where not null, asi evitaras todos los nulos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes apoyarte de una variable, suponiendo que `IdPaciente` es un `INT`:

- Declarar la variable `DECLARE @IdPaciente INT`
- Asingar el Id del paciente a buscar a esa variable `SET @IdPaciente = 2450`
- Validar que si el valor de la consulta es nulo ponga el valor de la variable `ISNULL(coalesce(Numeros.IdPaciente, datos.IdPaciente), @IdPaciente)`
- En las condiciones poner la igualdad pero con la variable `WHERE IdPaciente = @IdPaciente`

Finalmente quedaría lo siguiente:

```
DECLARE @IdPaciente INT
SET @IdPaciente = 2450

SELECT Numeros.n
    ,ISNULL(coalesce(Numeros.IdPaciente, datos.IdPaciente), @IdPaciente) AS IdPaciente
    ,FechaAnalitica
    ,GlucosaPre
    ,Sodio
    ,Calcio
FROM Numeros
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY IdPaciente ASC
            ) Row#
        ,IdPaciente
        ,FechaAnalitica
        ,GlucosaPre
        ,Sodio
        ,Calcio
    FROM ANA_BIOQUIMICA
    WHERE IdPaciente = @IdPaciente
    ) datos ON Numeros.n = datos.Row#
```

Answer (score 0):

Por la limitantes de tus comentarios, usa una subconsulta con `top 1` como 3ra opcion al `coalesce`:

```
select  Numeros.n ,
    coalesce(Numeros.IdPaciente, datos.IdPaciente,( select top 1 IdPaciente from Numeros where IdPaciente is not null ) ) IdPaciente,  
    FechaAnalitica,GlucosaPre,Sodio,Calcio from Numeros 
    left join
    (
    select ROW_NUMBER () over (order by IdPaciente asc) Row#,
    IdPaciente,FechaAnalitica,GlucosaPre,Sodio,Calcio
    from ANA_BIOQUIMICA where IdPaciente = 2450
    )datos
    on Numeros.n = datos.Row#
```

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por la respuestas, son funcionales, al final opte por usar la función LEAD de SQL.

```html
select IdPaciente, FechaAnalitica,GlucosaPre,Sodio,Calcio, lead(IdPaciente,1,0) over (Order by IdPaciente ) as Paciente from ( select datos.IdPaciente IdPaciente, FechaAnalitica, GlucosaPre, Sodio, Calcio from Numeros left join ( select ROW_NUMBER ()
over (order by IdPaciente asc) RowN, IdPaciente,FechaAnalitica,GlucosaPre,Sodio,Calcio from ANA_BIOQUIMICA where IdPaciente = 2450 )datos on Numeros.n = datos.RowN )d
```

esta genera justo lo que necesitaba  .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]